# Can't start activity in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps

i have some trouble with my android code

here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

        MapView mapView; 
        MapController mc;
        GeoPoint p;
        Button b;
        EditText e;
        TextView t;
        String x;
        String longi ;
        String lati ;
        Spinner naja;

        String[] jalan = {"A.Yani","Ambengan", "Anjasmoro","Baliwerti","Basuki Rahmat","Bintoro","Ciliwung","Darmo Raya","Darmokali","Diponegoro Raya","Dharmawangsa","Dinoyo","Embong Kemiri","Embong Malang"};
        class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
        {
            @Override
            public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
            boolean shadow, long when) 
            {
                super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

                //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
                Point screenPts = new Point();
                mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

                //---add the marker---
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.bawah);            
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
                return true;
            }
        } 
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            MapController mc = mapView.getController(); 
            switch (keyCode) 
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
                    mc.zoomIn();
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                    mc.zoomOut();
                    break;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }    
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
            View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

            naja=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.simpleGM_adress);
            ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, jalan);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
             naja.setAdapter(aa);
            t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.simpleGM_tv);
            e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.simpleGM_adress);
            zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
            mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
            /*
            mc = mapView.getController();
            String coordinates[] = {longi, lati};
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

            p = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (lat * 1E6), 
                (int) (lng * 1E6));

            mc.animateTo(p);
            mc.setZoom(17); 
            mapView.invalidate();
            mc.animateTo(p);
            mc.setZoom(17); 

            //---Add a location marker---
            MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.clear();
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

            mapView.invalidate();*/
        }


        public void clickHandler(View view){
            switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.simpleGM_btn_search:
                x = jalan[naja.getSelectedItemPosition()];
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama_jalan", x));
                /*            String valid = "1";*/ 
             String response = null;

             try {

                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.1.4/android/kordinat.php", postParameters);


                String result = response.toString();  
                //parse json data

                   try{
                           longi = "";
                           lati = "";

                     JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                           for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                                   JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                   Log.i("log_tag","nama_jalan: "+json_data.getString("nama_jalan")+
                                           ", latitude: "+json_data.getString("latitude")+
                                           ", longitude: "+json_data.getString("longitude")
                                   );
                                   if(result.equals(null)){
                                   //Get an output to the screen
                                  longi += "Data tidak ada";
                                   }
                                   else{
                                   lati += json_data.getString("latitude");
                                   longi += json_data.getString("longitude");
                                   }
                           }
                   }


                   catch(JSONException e){
                           Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                   }

                   try{
                       mc = mapView.getController();
                    String coordinates[] = {longi, lati};
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

                    p = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
                        (int) (lng * 1E6));

                    mc.animateTo(p);
                    mc.setZoom(17); 
                    mapView.invalidate();
                    mc.animateTo(p);
                    mc.setZoom(17); 

                    //---Add a location marker---
                    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                    listOfOverlays.clear();
                    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

                    mapView.invalidate();
                   }


                   catch(Exception e){

                    Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          

                   }   

              }

                    catch (Exception e) {

               Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     

              }
             break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    }
```

here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/simpleGM_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
    <TextView
android:id="@+id/simpleGM_tv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Tentukan Jalanmu"
android:layout_x="11px"
android:layout_y="5px"
>
</TextView>
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/simpleGM_adress" 
                android:layout_width="240px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:layout_x="12px"
android:layout_y="30px"
></Spinner>
<Button
android:id="@+id/simpleGM_btn_search"
android:layout_width="59px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="256px"
android:layout_y="30px"
android:text="find"
android:onClick="clickHandler"
>
</Button>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_x="2px"
android:layout_y="100px"
android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="00j2bA4ivSvH0cSDJJ4aiPiVCq_OSH0adwf6I2w"
    />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        /> 

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

and here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="udin.googlemaps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
</manifest>
```

when i run my program , it shows error like this

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{udin.googlemaps/udin.googlemaps.MainActivity} :
>         java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner "

can anyone help me to solve this error?

why this is happening?

any help will much appreciate.

Thank You.

Comment: I am guessing that  Spinner naja is not actualy a Spinner in your layout, but I have to see the xml first.

Comment: i have edit my question with add my main.xml

Comment: thanks....now i can run my program....thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of

```
   naja = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.simpleGM_adress);
```

and

```
   e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.simpleGM_adress);
```

The first one is a `Spinner`, not an `EditText`, you can't cast it to an EditText.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.xx( the widget type like  button or spinnar in ur case)  is because the widget defined in your XML  is not the same as the one you use in your java, so i recommand you to check your XML file (not mainfest file), or just post it here .